# adding arrays vs integers to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arraylist

As an exercise I am adding 7 integers (each integer is between 1 and 39) to an ArrayList and then printing out the integers with a for loop. I seem to be getting the expected output (Eg. Lottery numbers: 3 5 10 14 15 27 37). However my code is failing the automated test. The test gives the following error message: "The size of number list should be seven after drawNumbers call! expected:<7> but was:<14>"

I am thinking maybe I am adding the 7 integers as 14 individual numbers instead of 7 double digit integers. However, I am very unsure about that. It would be great to have some insight into what is going wrong.

The main program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LotteryNumbers lotteryNumbers = new LotteryNumbers();
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = lotteryNumbers.numbers();

        System.out.println("Lottery numbers:");
        for(int number : numbers) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

and the class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class LotteryNumbers {
    private final ArrayList<Integer> numbers;
    private final Random random;
    private int number;

    public LotteryNumbers() {
        this.numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.random = new Random();
        this.drawNumbers();
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> numbers() {
        return this.numbers;
    }

    public void drawNumbers() {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 7) {
            while(true) {
                this.number = random.nextInt(39)+1;
                if(!containsNumber(number)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.numbers.add(this.number);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public boolean containsNumber(int number) {
        return numbers.contains(number);
    }

}
```

Here is the testing code:

```
import fi.helsinki.cs.tmc.edutestutils.Points;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Points("82")
public class LotteryNumbersTest {

    public ArrayList<Integer> test() {
        LotteryNumbers lottoRivi;
        ArrayList<Integer> numerot;

        try {
            lottoRivi = new LotteryNumbers();
            numerot = lottoRivi.numbers();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            fail("Something went wrong when creating a new LotteryNumbers object! More info: " + t);
            return null; // tyhmä java
        }

        assertEquals("The size of number list should be seven!", 7, numerot.size());

        Set<Integer> jaljellaOlevatNumerot = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 39; i++) {
            jaljellaOlevatNumerot.add(i);
        }

        Set<Integer> arvotutNumerot = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i : numerot) {
            assertTrue("A lottery number should belong to range 1-39. However, you returned number: " + i,
                    (i >= 1 && i <= 39));
            assertTrue("The method containsNumber() returns false, despite the drawn number was among the list of drawn numbers: " + i,
                    lottoRivi.containsNumber(i));
            assertTrue("The numbers returned contain multiple times a number: " + i,
                    arvotutNumerot.add(i));
            jaljellaOlevatNumerot.remove(i);
        }

        for (int i : jaljellaOlevatNumerot) {
            assertFalse("The method containsNumber() returns true, despite the drawn number was not among the list of drawn numbers: " + i,
                    lottoRivi.containsNumber(i));
        }

        return numerot;
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        test();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDrawNumbersCallRemovesOldNumbersAndDrawsNew() {
        LotteryNumbers lottoRivi;
        ArrayList<Integer> numerot;
        try {
            lottoRivi = new LotteryNumbers();
            numerot = lottoRivi.numbers();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            fail("Something went wrong when creating a new LotteryNumbers object! More info: " + t);
            return;
        }
        String numerotString = numerot.toString();
        assertEquals("The size of number list should be seven!", 7, numerot.size());
        lottoRivi.drawNumbers();
        assertEquals("The size of number list should be seven after drawNumbers call!", 7, lottoRivi.numbers().size());
        assertFalse("New numbers should have been drawn with drawNumbers call! Numbers were " + numerotString,numerotString.equals(lottoRivi.numbers().toString()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMany() {
        int[] arr = new int[40];
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            for (int x : test()) {
                arr[x]++;
            }
        }

        int montako=0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 39; i++) {
            if (arr[i]>0) {
                montako++;
            }
        }

        assertEquals("200 lottery draws produced only " + montako +
                " different values! Not very random!", 39, montako);
    }
}
```

Having implemented @Eran's suggestion to put numbers.clear() as the first statement of the drawNumbers() method the code gave the correct output and passed the test. That enabled me to submit my code to the course provider (TestMyCode MOOC) and then view the model answer which I have pasted below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class LotteryNumbers {
    private ArrayList<Integer> numbers;

    public LotteryNumbers() {
        // Draw numbers as LotteryNumbers is created
        this.drawNumbers();
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> numbers() {
        return this.numbers;
    }

    public void drawNumbers() {
        // We'll format a list for the numbers
        this.numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // Write the number drawing here using the method containsNumber()
        Random random = new Random();
        while (this.numbers.size() < 7) {
            int newNumber = random.nextInt(39) + 1;
            boolean alreadyDrawn = this.containsNumber(newNumber);

            // we add the number only if it is not already among the drawn numbers
            if (!alreadyDrawn) {
                this.numbers.add(newNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean containsNumber(int number) {
        // Test here if the number is already in the drawn numbers
        for (int n : this.numbers) {
            if (n == number) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your JUnit test case that fails

Comment: What does the automated test expect?

Comment: @VHS  I have edited the post to show the test program. I am not sure if that is what you are after....

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I have edited the post to show the test program. Hope that is what you are after...

Comment: I am downvoting this question because the intention of the API is not clear, and requires deciphering the test case.  The test case shows: 1)  Calling the constructor should draw numbers, and 2)  `drawNumbers()` should clear the list prior to drawing new numbers.  The correct answer is not getting the right votes as a result, and the wrong answer is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `drawNumbers()` in the `LotteryNumbers` constructor, so after `LotteryNumbers` instance is created, it already contains 7 numbers.

Based on the message of the automated test - `The size of number list should be seven after drawNumbers call! expected:<7> but was:<14>` - it probably calls `drawNumbers()` again, which adds 7 more numbers to the list. Therefore you end up with 14 numbers.

You should remove the call to `drawNumbers()` from the constructor.

EDIT:

Seeing the testing method - `testDrawNumbersCallRemovesOldNumbersAndDrawsNew()` - you later added to the question, it expects the list to have 7 numbers before and after the call to `drawNumbers()`. Therefore you should keep `drawNumbers()` in the constructor, but clear the list at the beginning of `drawNumbers()` (by calling `numbers.clear()`).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn where do you see that drawNumbers clears the list?

Comment: @Eran I deleted drawNumbers() from the constructor and no numbers are output at all.

Comment: @user3425506 but your test method calls `lottoRivi.drawNumbers();`

Comment: @user3425506 if you want both your test method to succeed and your main method to output the numbers, you should remove the `drawNumbers()` call from the constructor and add it to the `main` method.

Comment: @Eran it is expected from the test. Check that the list only contains 7 numbers, call drawNumbers(), check the list still only contains 7 numbers (this fails), check that the numbers are not equal.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you are correct. I posted the answer before the test method was included in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, and that's why this question would normally get closed with the missing MCVE reason. You could not answer that question without the unit tests. Anyway, have an upvote.

Comment: @Eran I deleted drawNumbers() from the constructor and added it to the main method. The program gives the expected output but now completely fails the test (as opposed to partial fail before). The test error message is "The size of number list should be seven! expected:<7> but was:<0>"

Comment: @user3425506 yes, after reading your test method I edited the answer

Comment: @Eran Have put this.number.clear(); immediately before drawNumbers() but get original result ie test error message: "The size of number list should be seven after drawNumbers call! expected:<7> but was:<14>"

Comment: @user3425506 I meant you should put `numbers.clear()` inside `drawNumbers()` (as the first statement of that method).

Comment: @Eran That worked! I have edited the original post to point that out and also put the model answer which I have been able to view now that my code passed the test. I will mark your answer as accepted but will check out the other answers which I have not had time to do yet. Also I will try and understand the model answer which is a bit different from mine (ours)...

Answer (score 3):

The fix in this case is easy, just call `clear()` on the ArrayList at the beginning of `drawNumbers()`:

```
public void drawNumbers() {
    numbers.clear();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 7) {
        while(true) {
            this.number = random.nextInt(39)+1;
            if(!containsNumber(number)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        this.numbers.add(this.number);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Also, you should consider to only give out a copy of the ArrayList, so modifications on the ArrayList are not reflected in your class and vice versa.

Comment: Only just seen this as have been focussing on Eran's ideas which has led to the same conclusion...

Comment: Happens. We all sit sometimes in front of the solution and don't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

As Eran suggested, the problem is likely that the test case is explicitly calling `drawNumbers()`, thereby adding an additional 7 elements to the `numbers` List.

Think about what "drawNumbers" is supposed to do: should it *add* more numbers, or should it randomly draw a *replacement* set of numbers?

Since you don't ever clear the list of numbers, the code will enter an infinite loop if I `drawNumbers()` is called 5 times!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not adding integers as individual numbers.

In this case drawNumbers() method executed twice. You are calling it inside the constructor once then it would have called in the test case once, thats why the count is 14.

Comment the drawNumbers() in the constructor and add it to the main method

```
public LotteryNumbers() {
    this.numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.random = new Random();
    //this.drawNumbers();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LotteryNumbers lotteryNumbers = new LotteryNumbers();
    lotteryNumbers.drawNumbers();
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = lotteryNumbers.numbers();

    System.out.println("Lottery numbers:");
    for(int number : numbers) {
        System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(numbers.size());
}
```

Edit: After seeing the test cases, above answer is wrong. You have to add the clear() to the method as mentioned by others above